# How to fix - Functions are not valid as a React child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-class-based-component

I’m calling a function that returns some html code.

But if I want to send this function a parameter, then it tells me that **Functions are not valid as a React child**, the problem is that I want to access the props from the function, in order to do that, I changed the call in jsx as:

```
... ...
{this.showActivitiesIcon.bind(this)}
... ...
```

I tried setting a state inside the component, and setting the state from componentDidMount

```
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.setState({
            currentCountry: this.props.country
        })
    }
```

But, inside `componentDidMount`, there’s no such thing as `this.props.country`, and it’s useless to set `this.componentDidMount.bind(this)` inside the constructor. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax, because `bind(thisArg)` returns a function:

```
{this.showActivitiesIcon.bind(this)()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem like something:

```
super(props)
```

Can you share the whole code for this component?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're are not calling the function in your JSX.

Make sure you invoke it while using it so that it returns valid JSX.

```
this.showActivitiesIcon.bind(this)()
```